# Append data to csv columns python

Tags: python, csv

How the csv looks like

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
value1,value2,value3,value4,value5
,,value6,value7,value8,value9
,,value10,value11,value12,value13
```

how my function looks so far

```
def append(file, value1, value2):
    with open(file, 'a',) as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar=' ')
        writer.writerow([value1, value2])
```

The `append` function is called inside a function where value 1 and value 2 are passed from.

If the csv file looks like the below, the function does the job

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
value1,value2,value3,value4,value5
```

How could I write to a particular cell for as long as value1 and value2 are passed in.
Don't need to wory about the values being passed, just for the function to introduce the arguments.

the csv would look like:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
value1,value2,value3,value4,value5
,,value6,value7,value8,value9
,,value10,value11,value12,value13
```

Expected result

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
value1,value2,value3,value4,value5
argument1,argumen2,value6,value7,value8,value9
argument3,argument3,value10,value11,value12,value13
```

Comment: Use **\n** at begining of the line, and in the final.
The idea is know if your files always comes without the return of line.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the post, do you have a suggestion for the quotes?

Comment: Why are you using `newline=''` in the open command?

Comment: I forgot about it. When i started thinking about this I was convinced that i will write to it, but then i realised I need to append because writing will overwrite the file.

Comment: Read the two articles I think you can understand. https://thispointer.com/how-to-append-text-or-lines-to-a-file-in-python/

Comment: https://www.google.es/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/args-kwargs-python/amp/

Comment: I edit my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That way is how I was learned and is so easy:

```
def append_csv(file, *argv):
    my_line = ','.join([elem for elem in argv]) + '\n'
    file.write(my_line)
  
my_file = open('my_csv_file.csv', 'a')
append_csv(my_file, 'val1', 'val2', ... , 'valN')
my_file.close() # you need to close to save the changes.
```

Comment: I will give your code a try tmrw, but what i have it's pretty readable. your's is fancy.

Comment: don't know what type of code is that. is it python3.8 ?

Comment: When I put out of loop is a comment. Is Python3 yes. It is easier work with file.write instead of writer

Comment: I just updated the post, I found a bug that i did not consider, if you have the time to take a look.

Comment: It has a little job. Actually I will sleep, tomorrow I give you the answer. You can pass into function *args, and you don’t have to care about number of arguments

Comment: I am sorry. I think it was to late yesterday and I missed information from my problem. 
I've edited the post.
What I meant is that I have data in the file, but after the second line cels under column 1 and 2 would be empty and i would need a mechanism to fill them up with the arguments passed through the function param

Comment: your function looks nice and I learned something from it, I voted for it.
Rewrote it too, I think it looks better this way

def append_key(file, *argv):
    my_file = open(file, 'a')
    my_line = ','.join([elem for elem in argv]) + '\n'
    my_file.write(my_line)
    my_file.close()

Comment: Try to solve your problem, with this information you can do it yourself. If there miss any line of code I can help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232204/discussion-between-scilla-and-vahram-danielyan).